# Force sbt to re-read ~/sbt/plugins

Tags: scala, sbt

I am facultatively commenting out the `sbt-gpg-plugin` in `~/.sbt/plugin/build.sbt`, because I am using a lot of `publish-local` with different projects, and the query for the GPG password is getting totally on my nerves.

Now I need to re-**enable** that plugin because I want to push to Sonatype. But somehow sbt does not recheck `~/.sbt/plugin/build.sbt`, so even after editing it, uncommenting the line

```
addSbtPlugin( "com.jsuereth" % "xsbt-gpg-plugin" % "0.6" )
```

it still doesn't ask for the password to GPG sign the artifacts. I tried `clean`, `reload`, `reboot`, `reboot full`, no luck. I know I can reboot the computer, that usually works. But there must be some trick to force sbt to recheck `~/.sbt` and recognise the changes in their.

The problem seems to involve that the project itself has `project/plugins.sbt`, that somehow interferes with the global plugin caching. **sbt version is 0.11.3**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rather stupid solution, so please do add better answers:

```
$ mv ~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt ~/Desktop
$ sbt publish-local
```

This will try to reload the plugins, but fantastically asking them to come in flavour Scala 2.9.2 instead of Scala 2.9.1. So it will end up will problems finding the plugins. Then go back:

```
$ mv ~/Desktop/plugins.sbt ~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt
$ sbt publish-local
```

Re-downloads the plugins for Scala 2.9.1, and the GPG plugin is enabled. Voilà.

---

**Edit**: **Never ever try to move the file into the base directory `~/.sbt/` – you will [screw up so much](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768730/sbt-starts-to-ask-for-plugins-compiled-against-scala-2-9-2).**