# How to inform SBT to consume specific scala version for plugins? 

Tags: scala, sbt

Now I somehow messed up my global sbt plugins (`~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt`). They were always fine retrieved against Scala 2.9.1 which seems to be the version that sbt 0.11.3 wants, and all the plugins (sbt-gpg-plugin, sbt-idea-plugin) are published against 2.9.1.

Now whatever I do, it persistently tries to find them built against 2.9.2:

```
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:1.0.0 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.9.2)
[warn]      com.jsuereth:xsbt-gpg-plugin:0.6 (sbtVersion=0.11.3, scalaVersion=2.9.2)
...
[error] {file:...}default-50be6e/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;1.0.0: not found
```

How can I fix this, so sbt retrieves the plugins for Scala 2.9.1 as before?

---

For the sake of completeness, this is how my files look after the suggestions:

```
// project-home/build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.9.2"
...
```

```
// project-home/project/plugins.sbt
resolvers += "less is" at "http://repo.lessis.me"

addSbtPlugin( "me.lessis" % "ls-sbt" % "0.1.1" )

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"  // "just in case it helps"
```

```
// ~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.9.1"  // "just in case it helps"

resolvers += "sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/"

resolvers += Resolver.url( "sbt-plugin-releases", url( "http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases" ))( Resolver.ivyStylePatterns )

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin( "com.jsuereth" % "xsbt-gpg-plugin" % "0.6" )
```

---

What is even worse, the problem persists, even after I **removed** `~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt`. So there are no more references (at least visible to me) to either sbt-idea or xsbt-gpg-plugin. Still I cannot compile any project any more, because sbt still tries to find those two plugins. Epic fail.

Comment: It's just a warning, not error, but anyways why don't you try to write `scalaVersion := "2.9.1"` in plugins/build.sbt?

Comment: @om-nom-nom - unfortunately not, I edited the question and added the error line. Can't build. I don't want to write `scalaVersion := "2.9.1"`, because I want my __project__ artifacts published against 2.9.2. But stupid sbt 0.11.3 only accepted __plugins__ for 2.9.1. That's why they only exist online for 2.9.1 (like the idea plugin). But now suddenly it changed it's mind and wants 2.9.2. I am always trying to defend sbt publically, but these moment seriously make me question my own goodwill.

Comment: anyways, you can set scala version in build.sbt for plugins too. I've done this with 2.10-SNAPSHOT and this worked just fine

Comment: How do I do that? - If you paste that as an answer, there's a good chance I will close the question with that answer :)

Comment: try to wipe out yourproject/project/target directory (that's where compiled project config lives)

Comment: I wiped out all possible directories: `project-home/target`, `project-home/project/project`, `project-home/project/target`, `~/.sbt/plugins`, `~/.sbt/boot`, `~/.sbt/staging`, `~/.sbt/target`. Virtually everything except my Ivy2 cache, which I am not going to touch, because last time I removed that it took me an afternoon to get all my local artifacts back into there. (And it shouldn't have anything to do with Ivy)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could provide the Scala version of plugin. I didn't use ~/.sbt/, but I think it will works too.

The following is my project configuration using Scala 2.9.2 as my project compiler, and using some pluign that are compiled from Scala 2.9.1. Since Scala 2.9.1 and Scala 2.9.2 is binary compatible, I don't encounter any problem yet.

```
// MyProject/build.sbt

name := "MyProject"            

version := "0.1"            

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"
```

The following is plugin configuration:

```
// File: MyProject/project/plugins.sbt

import sbt._

import Defaults._

resolvers += Resolver.url("sbt-plugin-releases",
  new URL("http://scalasbt.artifactoryonline.com/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/"))(
    Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)


// Resolved to: 
//
//  http://..../com.untyped/sbt-less/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.3/0.4/jars/sbt-less.jar 
//
libraryDependencies += sbtPluginExtra(
    m = "com.untyped" % "sbt-less" % "0.4", // Plugin module name and version
    sbtV = "0.11.3",    // SBT version
    scalaV = "2.9.1"    // Scala version compiled the plugin
)
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, as outlined in my answer the problem was that somehow the plugins sneeked into the ivy.xml of a dependent project. But great info with `sbtPluginExtra`!

Answer (score 4):

Some references:

[SBT plugins are versioned to the scala version they were built with](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/ZYcA-A5qVgY).

[You're not the only one...](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/simple-build-tool/tVNhyrxv8gc)  Again, no answers.

[And another case study, this may have answers](https://github.com/mpeltonen/sbt-idea/issues/119).

A possibly relevant quote? " Remember to also remove the project/plugins -directory, because if the directory exists, project/plugins.sbt is ignored."

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify `sbtVersion` and `scalaVersion`. There is an overloaded `addSbtPlugin` -

```
addSbtPlugin(dependency : sbt.ModuleID, sbtVersion : scala.Predef.String, scalaVersion : scala.Predef.String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I went back to all the events that could have led to this. And because I found that other projects were still building, I started to understand that the problem with this particular project `B` was that it appeared that the two plugins were *regular dependencies* of project `A` which it depended on.

When sbt refused to acknowledge the presence of the GPG plugin which I uncommented in `~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt`, I *renamed that file* to `~/.sbt/plugins.sbt`, and back again. That intermediate position somehow meant that the plugins were not any more plugins (despite being added as `addSbtPlugin`), but regular dependencies for the project `A` when I publish that.

I tried to find that messed up `A`'s `ivy.xml` across all known Ivy2 cache directories. It was not possible to find the one that sbt was obviously seeing.

Long story, short answer: I had to bump the version of `A` artificially to get rid of the wrong `ivy.xml` cached somewhere in a hidden place. That forced sbt to re-find `A` with the correct `ivy.xml` (not depending any more on the plugins).

Now I'm just worried what happens if I put my global plugin settings into place :-#

---

Future advise: **Never ever ever put anything into `~/.sbt/plugins.sbt`. If you need sbt to understand that you changed `~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt`: Reboot your computer. Don't touch any file.**