# Why does SBT 0.12.2 resolve plugins with Scala 2.9.2 and ignore scalaVersion in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

SBT `0.12.2` **always** attempts to resolve plugins using Scala `2.9.2` when using the `%%` syntax on plugin imports.

I have tried setting older versions of Scala in `build.sbt`, newer versions, etc. Even deleting `target` folder each time... *nothing* seems to make a difference.

```
name := "Game"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1" // SBT is ignoring the scala version
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11768730/1305344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SBT is [recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#sbt-is-recursive), so you need to specify scala version for project, that build your project. Another words, you need to add appropriate `scalaVersion` to the `plugins.sbt` file.

Comment: This worked, thank you. However, if SBT is recursive, why doesn't it pick up the version from build.sbt, which is presumably parent to plugins.sbt?

Comment: Inner project is just another sbt project inside `project` folder, and doesn't inherit settings of outer one. You can ask on sbt mailing list why this approach was chosen.

Comment: So in what sense is SBT recursive? If settings are not inherited, then what? Is it purely in the sense that an SBT project is used to compile and SBT project?

Comment: Recursion is about __repeating__ things, not about __relations__ between things. sbt project is defined in scala, so it itself need to be built. Another sbt project is used to build first one. And latter one need to be built too. And so on. Thereby we have a __recursive__ project definition.

Answer (score 1):

For all plugins in your project, you set `scalaVersion` in `project/plugins.sbt` file that configures the build project definition for your project and where you define plugins.

```
$ cat project/plugins.sbt
scalaVersion := "2.9.3"
```

There's however a way to set up a more specific version of sbt and Scala for a plugin.

Instead of using `addSbtPlugin` that accepts a single `ModuleID` (constructed with `%` and `%%`), use `addSbtPlugin(dependency: ModuleID, sbtVersion: String)` or even `addSbtPlugin(dependency: ModuleID, sbtVersion: String, scalaVersion: String)`, e.g.

```
$ cat project/plugins.sbt
// It doesn't exist and it's only for demo purposes
addSbtPlugin("com.timushev.sbt" % "sbt-updates" % "0.1.0", "0.12.2", "2.5")
```